# Symfony2 Getting the Current User

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle

I'm developing an api, and I can't get the current user when I try the BasicAuth :

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object
```

Below you'll find the security.yml part that cause the error (I think it does) :

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern:        ^/
        anonymous:      true
        stateless:      true
        http_basic:
            realm:  "REST Service Realm"
            provider:   fos_userbundle

access_control:
    - { path: ^/users/me,       role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

I just put the path in access_control I'm testing. I've several more.

I'm using FOSRestBundle as well as FOSUserBundle (as you can see) and I didn't want to put a prefix, because it would be redundant :

```
// Routing.yml
rest : 
  type : rest 
  resource : "routing_rest.yml"
```

Now the part where the error occur is in the UserController (extending the FOSUser one) :

```
private function response($data, $status, $groups = array())
{
    $currentUser = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    if (!$currentUser)
        $groups = array("anon");
    else
    {
        if ($currentUser->hasRole("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"))
             array_push($groups, "admin");
        else if ($currentUser->hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN"))
             array_push($groups, "admin");
        else if ($currentUser->hasRole("ROLE_USER"))
             array_push($groups, "user");
    }
    return $this->view($data, $status)->setSerializationContext(SerializationContext::create()->setGroups($groups));
}
```

Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: euhm, where's the line that produces the error? would be nice to see the actual cause...

Comment: Sorry, I updated it.

Comment: call `$this->getUser();` directly within this controller -- see the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your token is null.  You have an unknown user if your token does not exist.

```
$token = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();
if (!$token) {
    return ('anon.');
} 
$user = $token->getUser();
```

Comment: As I stated in a previous comment, I used chrisben solution.
I think yours works too, but it's a bit longer. And I would have to check twice (for the token and the user).
But thanks a lot anyway =)